# How to Make particular option as selected in date range picker if i select it in seperate dropdown?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I Have a dropdown for selecting the date ranges like ("Last Month","This Month","Quarter1").

If i select Last Month in dropdown i am able to set those dates as selected in date range picker.

But option(Last Month) is not showing as selected in custom range options.
it's showing custom range as selected.

is it possible to make the custom option as selected ?

Comment: Show us your code and what you tried please

Comment: Please check the JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cm1n8r1k/19/

Comment: if i select last month or this month in dropdown dates are changing in date picker  but option is not showing as selected